# Deciding, whether a 1st-move player wins or not in a fibonacci coded game. Is there an algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, fibonacci

There's a Fibonacci code definied like that:

```
C(0) = 0
C(1) = 1
C(2) = 01
C(3) = 101
C(4) = 01101
C(5) = 10101101
.
.
.
```

There's a game using this coding system and a there's a board (eg. 1101101). In this game, players are removing Fibonecci's codes by turns (from the right to the left) out of the board. Player loses, if he can't remove anything anymore (the board becomes empty and now it's player's turn).

Is there a way to make an algorithm, that decides whether a player (that is doing 1st move) can always (always means independently from another player's movemenets) win or not.

egxample:

**Board**: 1101101

**Player1** - 1st move (01)  // possible movements (01, 1, 101, 01101)

**Board**: 11011

**Player2** - 2nd move (1)   // possible movements (1)

**Board**: 1101

**Player1** - 3rd move (01)  // possible movements (1, 01, 101)

**Board**: 11

**Player2** - 4th move (1)   // possible movements (1)

**Board**: 1

**Player1** - 5th move (1)  // possible movements (1)

**Board**:

**Player2** - 6th move (-)   // possible movements (none)

Comment: In your example, for the first move, there are also the possibilities `101` and `01101`, unless I misunderstood the rules.

Comment: Is there a limit on the size of the board?

Comment: @DanielFischer yea, You are right, thanks. dasblinkenlight There's no limit on the board's size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `n` be the length of the initial board, and let `board[i]` be the `i`-th symbol (from the left, 1-based indices) in the initial board, and `board[i..j]` the segment of the initial board between the indices `i` and `j` inclusive.

Let us call `i` a winning length if the player whose turn it is when `board[1..i]` is left can force a win, and a losing length if each possible move from `board[1..i]` leaves a winning length for the other player.

0 is a losing length (no possible move at all), and 1 is a winning length (removing the only remaining symbol immediately wins).

Each length is either winning or losing: if any possible move leaves a losing length for the other player, we can force a win by choosing that move, otherwise it's a losing length by definition.

We can find out whether we can force a win, together with a winning strategy if that is the case by noting for each length if it is losing (mark as `-1`) or what a win-forcing move would be (a non-negative integer `k` such that removing `C[k]` from the end of the remaining board leaves a losing length for the opponent; such a `k` is generally not unique, any will do).

Pseudocode (C-ish):

```
int moves[n+1];
// initialise all lengths to losing
for(i = 0; i <= n; ++i) {
    moves[i] = -1;
}
moves[1] = board[i]; // win by removing the last symbol
for(i = 2; i <= n; ++i) {
    if (board[i] == 0) {
        // no choice, the only code ending with a 0 is C[0]
        moves[i] = moves[i-1] < 0 ? 0 : -1;
    } else {
        k = 1;
        while(C[k] is_suffix_of board[1..i]) {
            if (moves[i - fib(k)] < 0) {
                // found a winning move
                moves[i] = k;
                break;
             }
             ++k;
        }
        // we either found a winning move and noted it, or leave the position as losing
    }
}
```

`moves[n]` tells us whether the first player can force a win, and if so, how.

The advantage over a pure brute-force is that it saves a lot of recomputation, since all states but the first few are reachable in many ways.

The `C[k] is_suffix_of board[1..i]` check is the most costly operation, it can be somewhat improved by noting that `C[k+1]` is the concatenation of `C[k-1]` and `C[k]` in that order, so when you know that `C[k]` is a suffix of `board[1..i]`, you only need to check whether `C[k-1]` is a suffix of `board[1..(i-fib(k))]`.

Comment: could You please say more precisely, whats in this line? moves[i] = moves[i-1] < 0 ? 0 : -1; Thanks :P

Comment: If the last digit is a 0, there is no choice, one must remove C(0). So then one checks whether what remains (the prefix one digit shorter) is a losing position (`moves[i-1] < 0`), if it is, we have a winning position and the winning move is removing C(0), hence then `moves[i]` becomes 0. If it is not a losing position (`moves[i-1] >= 0`), then `i` is losing, and we write a negative number (-1) to `moves[i]` to indicate that.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the length of your series, i would say just brute-force it....

Should not be to hard to write and keep track of all moves.